# Form error messages appearing in the middle of the form

Tags: theming, forms, commerce

I've got a hopefully EASY question. I'm using a Drupal Commerce-based form in my Drupal 7 site. The form has some required fields. When a user clicks the button to 'continue registration' at the bottom, and they hadn't filled out all the required fields, the form, of course, throws error messages in an error block that tells the user certain fields are required.

But the error messages are not showing up in the correct location. Please see the image below. The main error that there are problems with the form is displaying correctly at the top of the form, but then the problems with individual fields are displaying in THE MIDDLE OF THE FORM. Obviously, not ideal.

So, how do I make all the errors display at the top of the page?

I've already checked my tpl file for the page and the $messages variable is at the top.

[image]

Comment: Is it overlapping on the fields of the form?

Comment: yes, it is...i dont know why.

Comment: Strip all the css (using Web Developer plugin for Firefox or Chrome) OR change to the drupal default theme to check that it's not some css that is causing this. Also, use a javascript blocker, to check that there is no .js file that is causing this.

Comment: If it no longer overlaps after doing the above, then you found your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually due to the way the checkout module has been written (and is in line with recommended best practices for checkout form submission). The idea is to place the actual error message as close to the form element that generated it to reduce confusion in correcting errors on the form. There is no simple way to undo this behavior in the checkout module.

However, the fact that these are appearing halfway down the page is a good thing - what you really need to do is figure out what it is about your CSS that's causing the messages to float weirdly relative to your form elements.

Comment: Yeah, for the CSS probably need a clear:both and maybe even add the clearfix hack to the messages div element as well if the clear:both is a #failblog.

Comment: Adding clear: both to the .error class made the error block on its own line as suggested. It's below the title field...but not sure if there's any way to fix that given what was said above it being the default behavior to be inline.